# Is  quasi-factive relative to "hold-it-steady" obligations?

Tags: deontic-logic

Note: I don't know what the distinction between "held steady" and "made to be" obligations is usually called. What I mean by it: some things start out true, and we ought to keep them that way, whereas other things aren't yet true, and we ought to change things so that they are. Maybe "conservation" vs. "progression" are the words usually thought of in this connection. At any rate, for further illustrative purposes, consider the difference between:

1. This sentence ought to be kept true.
2. This sentence ought to be made true.

(2) is not yet true, so it's false, so it's not that it ought to be made true, so perhaps it's not possible to make it true (since ought-implies-can requires an ought to be in place, to be in force), so perhaps it's just false. I don't know how (1) could stop being true if it was true in the first place, but I also don't know that it's true in the first place.

Anyway, **OB** is the obligation operator, and any operator **X** is factive when **X***A* implies *A*. For example, the knowledge operator **K** is usually thought to be factive: if something is known, then it's true.

So, there are obligations for things to be changed such that **OB** is not factive relative to them, because they have yet to be discharged. So, however, is **OB** factive when it comes to "hold it steady" obligations? Since things are already as they ought to be, here, and they just need to be kept that way? We would write something like:

- **OB**<sup>K</sup>T*A* → T*A* (if it is obligatory that *A* be kept true, then *A* is true)

Or is **OB** still not factive if it's contingent that things be kept the way they ought to be kept? Since things could be changed so that *A* is not true? Do we need something besides mere factivity to make formal sense of things, here? I guess the keeping of *A* as true does not obtain until *A* is held true, so there would still be a sense of "something further to be done" in play (maybe *A* will cease to be true unless we hold it steady? but what about obligations to keep things true that aren't so "urgent"?), but I have to admit that my logical intuitions are going haywire right now, so I must wonder if basic factivity-talk is what's at stake in this kind of case.